# SQL filter countries by numbered region and also globally

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to build an SQL query using Microsoft SQL server, where countries can be filtered by regions numbered from 0 to 4, 0 meaning Global

I have constructed a query which filters the regions 1 to 4 correctly as per example below, but I can not figure out how to get all the countries if 0 (being Global) is selected as a region.

```
declare @region as integer
set @region = 1
select *
 from Country where 
 case LEFT(name,2) 
when 'US' THEN 1
when 'UK' THEN 2
WHEN 'DE' THEN 3
WHEN 'CZ' THEN 4
WHEN 'ES' THEN 4
WHEN 'FR' THEN 4
WHEN 'IT' THEN 4
WHEN 'NL' THEN 4
WHEN 'PL' THEN 4
WHEN 'RO' THEN 4
WHEN 'SE' THEN 4
END = @region
```

Any ideas? Is there better ways to construct the query?

Thanks

Comment: Can you add `region` as a **field** to `Country` table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To return all countries when `@region` is 0:

```
declare @region as integer
set @region = 1
select *
 from Country where 
    @region = 0
 OR
     case LEFT(name,2) 
        when 'US' THEN 1
        when 'UK' THEN 2
        WHEN 'DE' THEN 3
        WHEN 'CZ' THEN 4
        WHEN 'ES' THEN 4
        WHEN 'FR' THEN 4
        WHEN 'IT' THEN 4
        WHEN 'NL' THEN 4
        WHEN 'PL' THEN 4
        WHEN 'RO' THEN 4
        WHEN 'SE' THEN 4
    END = @region
```

Also, can you add region as a column to Country table? That would make the whole thing easier?

Comment: I agree, add the region to the base table. At least that makes it easier when you want to move countries from one region to another.

Comment: Not to mention that there's something around 200 countries. That will make a long query.

Comment: Thanks guys. I can not modify the table so I was looking for an alternative solution. this will work perfercely. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from Country 
where @region = 0 OR
(case LEFT(name,2) 
when 'US' THEN 1
when 'UK' THEN 2
WHEN 'DE' THEN 3
WHEN 'CZ' THEN 4
WHEN 'ES' THEN 4
WHEN 'FR' THEN 4
WHEN 'IT' THEN 4
WHEN 'NL' THEN 4
WHEN 'PL' THEN 4
WHEN 'RO' THEN 4
WHEN 'SE' THEN 4
END = @region)
```

Is the way to make it work.  However, instead of having this hard coded case statement, you should have a look up table that holds country names and the region code that is in.  Then you can rewrite the SQL statement to pull the country code from that table and compare it to region.

Answer (score 0):

you can put a field named region in country table 
then put this condition like below

```
   select * from Country where @region = 0 or Country.region =@region
```

you can do in your code like this

```
  select * from Country where @region = 0 OR (case LEFT(name,2) 
  when 'US' THEN 1
  when 'UK' THEN 2
  WHEN 'DE' THEN 3
  WHEN 'CZ' THEN 4
  WHEN 'ES' THEN 4
  WHEN 'FR' THEN 4
  WHEN 'IT' THEN 4
  WHEN 'NL' THEN 4
  WHEN 'PL' THEN 4
  WHEN 'RO' THEN 4
  WHEN 'SE' THEN 4
  END = @region)
```